# Arduino stops executing after about 9 loops

Tags: c, arduino

I have a sketch, which will execute around 9 times, before stopping. I tried freeing all of the arrays I had declared in the main loop, but that decreased the number of loops to 2 before stopping.

I have it checking the available memory, to see if maybe it is running out but there seem to be no leaks, according to MemoryFree. Maybe I coded something wrong?

```
// nrf24_reliable_datagram_client.pde
// -*- mode: C++ -*-
// Example sketch showing how to create a simple addressed, reliable messaging client
// with the RHReliableDatagram class, using the RH_NRF24 driver to control a NRF24 radio.
// It is designed to work with the other example nrf24_reliable_datagram_server
// Tested on Uno with Sparkfun WRL-00691 NRF24L01 module
// Tested on Teensy with Sparkfun WRL-00691 NRF24L01 module
// Tested on Anarduino Mini (http://www.anarduino.com/mini/) with RFM73 module
// Tested on Arduino Mega with Sparkfun WRL-00691 NRF25L01 module

#include <RHReliableDatagram.h>
#include <RH_NRF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <MemoryFree.h>

DHT dht(5, DHT22);
#define CLIENT_ADDRESS 1
#define SERVER_ADDRESS 2

// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_NRF24 driver;
// RH_NRF24 driver(8, 7);   // For RFM73 on Anarduino Mini

// Class to manage message delivery and receipt, using the driver declared above
RHReliableDatagram manager(driver, CLIENT_ADDRESS);

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (!manager.init())
    Serial.println("init failed");
  // Defaults after init are 2.402 GHz (channel 2), 2Mbps, 0dBm
  dht.begin();
}

uint8_t data[70];
// Dont put this on the stack:
uint8_t buf[RH_NRF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];

void looop()
{
  byte data[2];

  getdat(&data[0]);
}

void getdat(byte *pdata)
{
  pdata[0] = 'a';
  pdata[1] = 'b';
}

double getAvgRead(int readDelay, int iterations, double* result){
  int startMillis = millis();
  int iterationStart, i;
  for (i = 0 ; i < iterations; i++){
    iterationStart = millis();

    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    result[0] += dht.readTemperature(true);
    //Serial.println(result[0]);
    result[1] += dht.readHumidity();
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);

    delay(readDelay-millis()+iterationStart);
  }

  result[0] /= i; //divide by iterations to produce the average
  result[1] /= i;
  //Serial.println(result[0]);
}

int i = 0;
void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Sending, loop " + String(i++) + ", mem: " + String(freeMemory()));
  //int s = millis();
  double values[2] = {0,0};
  getAvgRead(2020,1,values);
  //Serial.println((millis()-s));

  uint8_t data[28];
  char str[28];
  sprintf(str,"U,DHT;T,%d;H,%d", (int)(values[0] * 100.0), (int)(values[1] * 100.0));
  memcpy(data,(uint8_t*)str,sizeof(str));
  Serial.println((char*)data);

  // Send a message to manager_server
  if (manager.sendtoWait(data, sizeof(data), SERVER_ADDRESS))
  {
    // Now wait for a reply from the server
    uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
    uint8_t from;   

    manager.recvfromAckTimeout(buf, &len, 2000, &from);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("sendtoWait failed");
}
```

Introducing the getAvgRead function caused this error. I have missed something maybe?

Edit: This sketch is meant to read from a DHT sensor a bunch of times, average out the readings, then transmit it to another arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve with this sketch but having had a look at the code I suspect that your problem will be the line:

```
delay(readDelay-millis()+iterationStart);
```

I suspect you are trying to make each iteration take exactly `readDelay` milliseconds. If the iteration takes longer than `readDelay` then the delay will be negative. I assume a negative `delay` parameter will wrap around to a very large unsigned integer.  Perhaps you should check the calculated delay and skip the delay if it is negative.

Also, as @m0nk3y suggests in the comments, you should also change your `readDelay`, `startMillis`, and `iterationStart` variables to `unsigned long`s.

This `delay` is certainly where I'd start looking first. Of course, it is also entirely possible that I am barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: That line tells it to pause for the rest of the interation duration. Should be the same as delay(readDelay-(millis()-iterationStart)). It calates how many milliseconds have passed since the start of this iteration, then waits so that the iteration last X amount of milliseconds. readDelay is misnamed because i changed the paramaters and forgot about it.

Comment: Yeah I've just realised that.  What happens if you just set the delay to readDelay.  Does the sketch stop running.

Comment: What happens if you hard code the delay value, perhaps just set it to `readDelay`? I have also updated my answer with a suggestion that the delay may be ending up negative.

Comment: I just changed it to delay(readDelay) and it executed twice as long as previously, this may have somehow been it. I am stumped. I'm trying `delay(readDelay-(millis()-iterationStart))` to see if that works better.

Comment: Does changing your millis variables to `unsigned long` help? From [link](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/millis): Note that the parameter for millis is an unsigned long, errors may be generated if a programmer tries to do math with other datatypes such as ints.

Comment: @m0nk3y I was just about to suggest the same thing myself :)

Comment: I just looked up the max value for unsigned long and I think it will be fine actually. Thanks :-)